# getting an error while converting from json to data frame in R

Tags: r, json, list, dataframe

I am trying to convert my json file into a data frame in R but I am getting error.

What I did:

```
 install.packages("rjson")
 # Load the package required to read JSON files.
 library("rjson")
 # Give the input file name to the function.
 result <- fromJSON(file = "myJsonFile.json")
 # Convert JSON file to a data frame.
 json_data_frame <- as.data.frame(result)
```

Error that I am getting is:

```
Error in (function (..., row.names = NULL, check.rows = FALSE, check.names = TRUE,  : 
arguments imply differing number of rows: 2, 1, 8, 4, 9, 7, 0, 3, 37, 5, 104, 6, 17, 14, 102, 
11, 144, 15, 88, 127, 130, 29, 12, 45, 82, 69, 13, 50, 10, 92, 41, 55, 53, 24, 72, 19, 18, 
134, 51, 16, 62, 54, 132, 148, 95, 20, 131, 39, 36, 38, 44, 42, 133, 64, 33, 93, 65, 22, 73, 
63, 85, 57, 135, 46, 110, 91, 43, 173, 81, 49, 71, 21, 32, 136, 28, 84, 31, 99, 149, 126, 52, 
114, 77, 61, 94, 87, 26, 34, 67, 90, 23, 75, 25, 79, 30
```

The structure of my json file is:

```
List of 1193
$ 0   : chr [1:2] "e958e6a0-4546-6861-9a40-c3f267675b7e" "26a698a1-855c-f479-984b-60c81f4e1d32"
$ 1   : chr [1:2] "28fb85b7-8b15-bf7a-0fc9-3511d40869b4" "b41afb42-48e3-640a-3ec3-ffb528af182b"
$ 2   : chr "20a8ed50-e592-70e4-aecd-ec17f1723495"...
```

I have upto $1192

A snippet of the json file is like this:

[image]

The $0 and $1 are my contig ids and the big number are the long read ids. I am not able to give the column names too.
Kindly help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you have lists of different lengths you can get the maximum length and append `NA`'s at the end. Try,

```
n <- 1:max(lengths(result))
out <- do.call(cbind, lapply(result, `[`, n))
```